# Iterating over nested sequence in F# - How?

Tags: f#, nested, iteration, sequence

I can define a simple list in F# as follows and iterate over it with the following code:

```
let ar = [0;1;2;3]
ar |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "Ar: %A" x)
```

Now consider a nested sequence as follows:

```
let ar1 = [1;2;3;4]
let ar2 = [5;6;7;8]
let nested_array = [ar1; ar2]
```

How can I Iterate over this - the following code below gets an error:

> 'Unexpected infix operator in lambda expression'

What I'm trying to do here is to iterate over the outer sequence and pipe that forward to a second iterator which then lets me access the contents of the inner arrays.

```
nested_array |>
Seq.iter (fun x -> |> 
                    Seq.iter  (fun y ->
                    printfn "Ar: %A" y))
```

What am I missing here - I suspect a syntax problem or (more serious/likely) a lack of F#/FP comprehension .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not using your variable `x`.  Try either

```
nested_array |> Seq.iter (fun x -> x |> Seq.iter (fun y -> printfn "Ar: %A" y))
```

or (eliminating the use of `x` entirely)

```
nested_array |> Seq.iter (Seq.iter (fun y -> printfn "Ar: %A" y))
```

or even (eliminating `y` as well)

```
nested_array |> Seq.iter (Seq.iter (printfn "Ar: %A"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't generally like using `Seq.iter` function when it is not in a part of a larger processing pipeline. The alternative is to just use nested `for`:

```
for nested in nested_array do
  for y in nested do printfn "Ar: %A" y
```

Although, it's true that using partial function application (as posted by kvb) nakes it quite nice, so it is just a matter of personal preference - and who you expect to read it. I guess my approach is not to make the source code "more clever" if it doesn't give you any clear value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

nested_array |> Seq.iter (fun x -> x |> Seq.iter (printfn "%d"))